# How to use option to specify file name extensions for ack?

Tags: command-line-arguments, ack

I'd like to specify the file name extensions when searching in a folder of files.  Read the man page of ack and still confused.   Why something like the following not working?

```
ack --type-add=xlog=.xlog "foobar"
```

**Update**

I use ack 2.14 under Perl 5.16.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming you're using ack 2.x, because the filetype rules are very different in ack 2.x than 1.x.

Your `--type-add=xlog=.xlog` told ack about the filetype "xlog", but you didn't do anything with it. Do you *only* want to search .xlog files?  Then you need `--xlog`.  Are you trying to exclude .xlog files from your searching?  If so, then you need to say `--noxlog`.

So if you only want .xlog files, you do

```
ack --type-add=xlog=.xlog --xlog text-to-search-for
```

Now, that's a pain to type over and over again, so you can put

```
--type-add=xlog=.xlog
```

into an ackrc file (either /etc/ackrc or ~/.ackrc or somewhere in your project directory) and then you only need to do

```
ack --xlog text-to-search-for
```